# Custom numeric format string in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, string-formatting

I'm trying to learn Visual Basic .NET step by step, but now I have a problem with a custom numeric format string using the String.Format() method.

I have an Integer variable like this

`Dim x As Integer = 123456`

and I want to format it to 1,234.56 with the String.Format() method.
I believed that the following was the correct format but it doesn't work:

`String.Format("#,###.##", x)`

What is the correct format string to get the result that I need?.

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: `String.Format("{0:#,###.##}", x / 100)`  note that your value is an int, so to get the decimals, you have to convert to decimal

Comment: @Plutonix the / operator behaves differently in C# and VB.NET. You could write `Dim result = String.Format("{0:N}", x/100)` and get the correct number of decimals while in C# it fails without the conversion to double of the constant `100d` Oh well sometimes simple questions have hidden secrets

Comment: Thank you. The last two answers work fine. Simple and effective. @MitchWheat Thanks for the link. When I have more time I will take a look it

Comment: Oh, thanks for the negative vote. It makes me feel like a stupid.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what Plutonix is saying, you could do it using a simple function:

```
Public Function FormatInt(format As String, arg As Integer) As String
    Dim ArgString As String = arg.ToString
    Dim Result As String = ""

    Dim FormatIndex As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To format.Length - 1
        If format.Substring(i, 1) = "#" Then
            Result = Result + ArgString.Substring(FormatIndex, 1)
            FormatIndex = FormatIndex + 1
        Else
            Result = Result + format.Substring(i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    Return Result
End Function
```

This might not be the best solution, but it is very simple to use:

```
Dim x As Integer = 123456    
FormatInt("#,##.##",x)
```

Too make it work the other way around (reverse it) you can just reverse the process. It doesn't work like the String.Format() method does, but I believe it suits your needs

Comment: The output for  `FormatInt("#,###.##",x)` is 1,234.56 
It is the expected result, but @Plutonix gave me an easier solution:
`String.Format("{0:N}", x/100)`

Answer (score 0):

```
x.tostring("n2")
```

It will display your result as 123,456.00 in your example above.

Not you can use N or N0 up to any digit you want like N2 , N3 , ....